# How to get substring of comma delimited string?

Tags: php, string, substring, explode

I have a comma delimited string and want the first 100 entries (not including the 100th comma) as a single string.

So for example if I had the string

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

And the problem was get the first 3 entries, the desired result string would be

```
a,b,c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using explode/implode:

```
$str     = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g';
$temp1   = explode(',',$str);
$temp2   = array_slice($temp1, 0, 3);
$new_str = implode(',', $temp2);
```

Using regex:

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/^((?:[^,]+,){2}[^,]+).*$/','\1',$str);
```

Comment: If you're going to use `explode` for this, pass in the `limit` 3rd parameter set to 1 + the number of items you want to limit wasted effort. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

try php's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$string_array = explode(",",$string);
```

Loop through the array to get the values you want:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($string_array); $i++)
{
echo $string_array[$i];//display values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by finding the 100th delimiter:

```
$delimiter = ',';
$count = 100;
$offset = 0;
while((FALSE !== ($r = strpos($subject, $delimiter, $offset))) && $count--)
{
    $offset = $r + !!$count;
}
echo substr($subject, 0, $offset), "\n";
```

or similarly tokenize it:

```
$delimiter = ',';
$count = 100;
$len = 0;
$tok = strtok($subject, $delimiter);
while($tok !== FALSE && $count--)
{
    $len += strlen($tok) + !!$count;
    $tok = strtok($delimiter);
}
echo substr($subject, 0, $len), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split the string after a comma and put the first 100 indexes together (comma-separated). 
Before this you have to check if count(array) is greater or smaller than 100.